# Variable row heights in JTable; Better way than storing height values in hidden table model column?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am writing a cell renderer for a JTable that allows each row to have a different height. For each column in my table, i have added an adjacent hidden column to the table that simply contains an int value for the row height. I think this will be inefficient and pose problems down the line when I implement more complex resizing.

Is there a way to have a static list initialized by the main class, that can be accessed by getTableCellRendererComponent?

Here's a standalone example of what I'm currently doing:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;


public class variableRowHeightDemo extends JFrame {

    public variableRowHeightDemo() {
        JTable vr_table = new JTable();

        vr_table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
                new Object[][]{
                    {"Height: 30", 30},
                    {"Height: 60", 60},
                    {"Height: 90", 90},},
                new String[]{
                    "String", "int height value"
                }));

        vr_table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new variableRowHeightRenderer());

        add(vr_table);
        pack();
    }

    static class variableRowHeightRenderer extends JTextField implements TableCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
                int col) {

            // rows heights stored in second invis column
            int height = (int) table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 1);
            table.setRowHeight(row, height);

            this.setText(value.toString());
            return this;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new variableRowHeightDemo().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Basically, I want to store the row heights outside of the table model, but I am unsure how to go about accessing them from a subclass without making the list of row heights final. Also, if there are any glaring problems with my implementation I would be grateful to hear them.

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
table.setRowHeight(row, height);
```

That line of code should not be used in a renderer. You should not change the property of the table from within the render. The code you posted will cause an infinite loop because the renderer changes the height, then the table repaints the row...

> Basically, I want to store the row heights outside of the table model,

Whats wrong with using the table.setRowHeight() method when you add data to the model? You can update the table at the same time.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? I haven't been able to call setRowHeight() outside the renderer without it changing every row to that height. 
Also, I didn't realised it was infinitely repainting, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: There is nothing more to explain. You specify the row and height for the method. Make sure you are not using the setRowHeight(height) method. This will change the height for all the rows.

Comment: Thanks camickr, the setRowHeight(int,int) method escaped me.